# What is the equivalent of ExternalResource and TemporaryFolder in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, temporary-files, junit5

According to the [JUnit 5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rulesupport), JUnit Jupiter provides backwards compatibility for some JUnit 4 Rules in order to assist with migration.

> As stated above, JUnit Jupiter does not and will not support JUnit 4 rules natively. The JUnit team realizes, however, that many organizations, especially large ones, are likely to have large JUnit 4 codebases including custom rules. To serve these organizations and enable a gradual migration path the JUnit team has decided to support a selection of JUnit 4 rules verbatim within JUnit Jupiter.

The guide goes on to say that one of the rules is [ExternalResource](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html), which is a parent for [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html).

However, the guide unfortunately doesn't go on to say what the migration path is, or what the equivalent is for those writing new JUnit 5 tests. So what should we use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JUnit 5.4 comes with a built-in extension to handle temporary directories in tests.

`@org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir` annotation can be used in order to annotate class field or a parameter in a lifecycle (e.g. `@BeforeEach`) or test method of type `File` or `Path`.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDir;

@Test
void writesContentToFile(@TempDir Path tempDir) throws IOException {
    // arrange
    Path output = tempDir
            .resolve("output.txt");

    // act
    fileWriter.writeTo(output.toString(), "test");

    // assert
    assertAll(
            () -> assertTrue(Files.exists(output)),
            () -> assertLinesMatch(List.of("test"), Files.readAllLines(output))
    );
}
```

You can read more on this in my blog post, where you will find some more examples on utilizing this built-in extension: https://blog.codeleak.pl/2019/03/temporary-directories-in-junit-5-tests.html.

Answer (score 8):

[Interesting article by author of TemporaryFolderExtension for JUnit5](http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/04/06/replace-rules-in-junit5/)

and

[his code repo on github](https://github.com/rherrmann/junit5-experiments)

JUnit5.0.0 is now in general release so let's hope they turn their attention to making the experimental stuff production-ready.

Meanwhile, it seems the TemporaryFolder rule will still work with JUnit5 [docs](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-rule-support)

use this:

```
@EnableRuleMigrationSupport
public class MyJUnit5Test {
```

and this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understood, there can be no one to one mapping from `ExternalResource` to an equivalent in JUnit5. The concepts just don't fit. In JUnit4, the `ExternalResource` basically gives you a `before` and an `after` callback, but within the rule, you have no control about what `before` and `after` actually means. You could use it with `@Rule` or with `@ClassRule`.

In JUnit5, the extension is defined to hook in specific [extension points](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks) and thus the 'when' is well defined.

Another difference in concepts would be, that you can have a state in JUnit4 rules, but your JUnit5 extensions shouldn't have any state. Instead, all state should go to the [execution context](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-keeping-state).

Nevertheless, here is an option I came along with, where `before` and `after` relates to each test method:

```
public abstract class ExternalResourceExtension 
  implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback, AfterTestExecutionCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        before(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        after(context);
    }

    protected abstract void before(ExtensionContext context);

    protected abstract void after(ExtensionContext context);
}
```

Comment: ExternalResource was usable before to setup contingent objects used by all tests, how can extensions replace this functionality if they can't have any instance members? Any idea how code outside of an extension is supposed to acquire anything that the extension has prepared (such as an EJB container)?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for that is still in the making - see [pull request #660](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/660).

Answer (score 3):

Temporary folders now have a solution in the way of [`@TempDir`](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-temporary-directory).  However, what about the idea behind `ExternalResource`s in general?  Perhaps it's for a mock database, a mock HTTP connection, or some other custom resource you want to add support for?

The answer, it turns out is you can use the [`@RegisterExtension`](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-registerextension-annotation) annotation to achieve something quite similar.

Example of use:

```
/**
 * This is my resource shared across all tests
 */
@RegisterExtension
static final MyResourceExtension MY_RESOURCE = new MyResourceExtension();

/**
 * This is my per test resource
 */
@RegisterExtension
final MyResourceExtension myResource = new MyResourceExtension();

@Test
void test() {
    MY_RESOURCE.doStuff();
    myResource.doStuff();
}
```

And here's the basic scaffolding of `MyResourceExtension`:

```
public class MyResourceExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback,
        BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    private SomeResource someResource;

    private int referenceCount;

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        beforeEach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        afterEach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (++referenceCount == 1) {
            // Do stuff in preparation
            this.someResource = ...;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        if (--referenceCount == 0) {
            // Do stuff to clean up
            this.someResource.close();
            this.someResource = null;
        }
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        return this.someResource.fooBar();
    }

}
```

You could of course wrap this all up as an abstract class and have `MyResourceExtension` implement just `protected void before()` and `protected void after()` or some such, if that's your thing, but I'm omitting that for brevity.